# Exclude a pattern in RegEx

Tags: regex

I want a RegEx to match any Hex number but `7E` and `7D`.

To match any Hex number I use `[0-9A-F]{2}`. How can I now exclude the unwandted numbers?

Comment: Most engines or programs have some kind of 'not' function that is mostly much more effective than regexp that matches everything 'but'.
I'd suggest you to look that way first, then use complex things as desc. in answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a negative look-ahead that would fail on `7E` or `7D`. The following pattern uses `^` and `$` to match the entire string, not a partial match within a string.

```
^(?!7[ED])[0-9A-F]{2}$
```

Comment: Thanks this worked. I don't need the '^' and '$' since I use the RegEx as terminal in a parser generated with TinyPG.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like this:

`[0-68-F][0-F] || 7[0-CF]`

(the `||` might not work, depending on where you're using this regex. You didn't specify that in your question)

Answer (score 0):

`[0-9A-F&&[^7]][0-9A-F&&[^DE]]`

Comment: Id didn't work. I think that would ignore any Hex Number that has the fist digit 7 and the second digit D od E.